# How to plot array in VBA?

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, function, plot

I want to create a function `plot_array(arr As Variant)` which will create plot based on element in array.
On x axis I want to have numbers 1, 2,.., n which are indexes of array elements, and on y axis I want to have values stored in array. In other words

[image]

**Example**

```
Dim arr(9) As Variant
arr(0) = 0
arr(1) = 1
arr(2) = 5
arr(3) = 1
arr(4) = 5
arr(5) = 5
arr(6) = 1
arr(7) = 7
arr(8) = 6 

plot_array(arr)
```

[image]

I tried to figure it about by running Macros and thinking how can I generalize this code to be working for any array, but I end up with nothing. Is there any possibility how it can be done ?

Comment: Are you willing to first store your values in worksheet cells ??

Comment: Yes, I prefer solution to have them first in your worksheet cells ;))

Comment: Refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64235645/excel-vba-for-making-multiple-graph-without-using-range/64244924?r=SearchResults#64244924).  An array of x-axis values is created on the x-axis, and a y-axis array is created and substituted on the y-axis.

Answer (score 0):

Try the next code, please. It will create a chart (xlLine type) and feed it with the array. You can change in the line `.SeriesCollection.NewSeries.Values = arr1` `arr1` with `arr` and obtain the same thing, if you put all the used number in the range "A1:A9":

```
Sub testPlotChartArray()
  Dim sh As Worksheet, cH As Chart, arr1, arr(1 To 9)
  
  Set sh = ActiveSheet
  arr1 = sh.Range("A1:A9").Value
  arr(1) = 0: arr(2) = 1: arr(3) = 5: arr(4) = 1: arr(5) = 5
  arr(6) = 5: arr(7) = 1: arr(8) = 7: arr(9) = 6
  On Error Resume Next
   Set cH = sh.ChartObjects("PlotChart").Chart
   If Err.Number = 0 Then
        Err.Clear
        cH.Parent.Delete
   End If
  On Error GoTo 0
  
  Set cH = sh.ChartObjects.Add(left:=60, top:=10, width:=300, height:=300).Chart
  With cH
    .Parent.Name = "PlotChart"
    .ChartType = xlLine
    .SeriesCollection.NewSeries.Values = arr1 'or arr
  End With
End Sub
```

The above code deletes the chart if it exists, but it can be configured to use the same existing chart and feed its `.SeriesCollection(1).Values`...

Comment: @John: Didn't you find some time to check the above code?

Answer (score 0):

If you declare an array as arr(9) in Excel, the index is declared as a total of 10 arrays from 0 to 9, so your array is not the correct number.

```
Sub test()
    Dim arr(8) As Variant
    arr(0) = 0
    arr(1) = 1
    arr(2) = 5
    arr(3) = 1
    arr(4) = 5
    arr(5) = 5
    arr(6) = 1
    arr(7) = 7
    arr(8) = 6

    plot_array (arr)
    
End Sub
Sub plot_array(arr As Variant)
    Dim Srs As Series
    Dim Cht As Chart
    Dim xAxes As Axis, yAxes As Axis
    Dim i As Integer, vX() As Variant
    
    ReDim vX(LBound(arr) To UBound(arr))
    
    For i = LBound(arr) To UBound(arr)
        vX(i) = i + 1 '<~~ if index start from 0 then delete +1
    Next i
    
    Set Cht = ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart.Chart
    With Cht
        .HasTitle = True
        .ChartTitle.Text = "My Graph"
        .ChartType = xlXYScatterLinesNoMarkers
        For Each Srs In .SeriesCollection
            Srs.Delete
        Next Srs
        Set Srs = .SeriesCollection.NewSeries
        With Srs
            .Name = "item"
            .Values = arr
            .XValues = vX
            .MarkerStyle = xlCircle
        End With
        Set xAxes = .Axes(xlCategory, xlPrimary)
        With xAxes
            .MinimumScale = 0
            .MaximumScale = WorksheetFunction.Max(vX)
            .MajorUnit = 1
            .HasMajorGridlines = True
        End With
        Set yAxes = .Axes(xlValue, xlPrimary)
        With yAxes
            .MinimumScale = 0
            .MaximumScale = WorksheetFunction.Max(arr) + 1
            .MajorUnit = 1
            .HasMajorGridlines = True
        End With
            
        
    End With
End Sub
```