# trouble plotting graph using userfom time interval data

Tags: excel, vba

I faced error 438 at .HasTitle = True. There is a problem at with chtChart subsection as i place .charttype at the third line, Excel always prompt me that there is an error of 438
Edited codes:

```
    Dim chtChart As ChartObject
    Dim maxscale As Long, LastRowOfA As Long
    Dim xAxes As Axis, yAxes As Axis
    Set chtChart = ActiveSheet.ChartObjects(1)
    maxscale = ActiveSheet.Cells(LastRowOfA, 1)
    LastRowOfA = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row


    With chtChart
        .HasTitle = True
        .ChartTitle.Text = "X VS Y"
        .ChartType = xlXYScatterLinesNoMarkers
        .SeriesCollection.NewSeries
        With .SeriesCollection(1)
            .XValues = ActiveSheet.Range("A2:A" & LastRowOfA)
            .Values = ActiveSheet.Range(Range("B2:B" & LastRowOfB))
        End With
        
        Set xAxes = .Axes(xlCategory, xlPrimary)
            With xAxes
                .HasTitle = True                               
                .AxisTitle.Text = "Category (X) Axis"             
                .MinimumScale = 0                              
                .MaximumScale = maxscale                       
                .MajorUnit = tbData
            End With
        
        Set yAxes = .Axes(xlValue, xlPrimary)
            With yAxes                                          
                .HasTitle = True
                .AxisTitle.Text = "Category (Y) Axis"
                .MinimumScaleIsAuto = True                      
                .MaximumScaleIsAuto = True                      
            End With
    End With
```

Comment: You haven't set `chtChart` to a chartobject...    What cell formatting do you have on `ColumnARngData` ?

Comment: How do i do so? Is it set chtChart = ActiveSheet.ChartObjects? The format is general

Comment: Well does the chart already exist?  I can't see your sheet...

Comment: the chart does not exist.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.chartobjects.add

Comment: `Set chtChart = ActiveSheet.ChartObjects.Add(50, 50, 200, 200)`  for example

Comment: i receive runtime error 13 when i use that code

Comment: That line works fine for me...

Comment: Maybe update your post with your current code...

Comment: I have updated my codes, i still face the same problem with  Set chtChart = ActiveSheet.ChartObjects

Comment: you missed the `.Add()` part

Answer (score 0):

If there is only one Chartobject, do the following.

```
Set chtChart = ActiveSheet.ChartObjects(1)
with chtChart.Chart
.....
```

Comment: The code works but why at .MinimumScale it dosent? I recieved an called error 438

Comment: @Chewjunnie, refer [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65594185/how-to-plot-array-in-vba/65608806#65608806).

Comment: @Chewjunnie, First, you need to set the .ChartType. You can specify the scale of the x-axis only in the scatter chart. And you also have to set the axis.

Comment: I did but i still facing error 438. Why is it so?

Comment: @Chewjunnie, not `With chtChart`  to `With chtChart.chart`.  chartobject is not chart.